# Why the scanf function is expecting a pointer type in C?

Tags: c, pointers, state-machine

I am writing the c code to implement the following state machine:
[image] (from [TI-RSLK](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/swrp161/swrp161.pdf?ts=1668646360028&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)). Here please find the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct state{
    unsigned int output;
    unsigned int delay;
    const struct state *next[4];
};

#define center &fsm[0]
#define left &fsm[1]
#define right &fsm[2]

typedef const struct state state_t;

state_t fsm[3] = {
    {3, 50, {right, left, right, center}},
    {2, 50, {left, center, right, center}},
    {1, 50, {right, left, center, center}}
};

int main(void)
{
    state_t *spt; 
    unsigned int input;
    unsigned int output;
    spt = center;
    while(1) {
        output = spt->output;
        printf("%u \n", output);  
        scanf("%u \n", input);
        spt = spt->next[input]; 
    }
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code will return an error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:37:17: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
   37 |         scanf("%u \n", input);
      |                ~^      ~~~~~
      |                 |      |
      |                 |      unsigned int
      |                 unsigned int *
3
```

I thought '%u' accepts an unsigned integer. Why does it refer to a pointer of unsigned int type here?

I also tried '%d'. I thought '%d' would accept an integer. The error also indicates that a pointer (of type integer) is expected.

Thank you for any discussions!

Comment: Some note to improve further questions: If you are asking about a specific function taking certain parameters, then it does not at all matter what the program should do. There is no need to add that state machine diagram. Also for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you don't need that struct definition or that array etc. Remove everything that does not provide any extra value to the example. Details that are not required only distract people reading your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, it isn't `printf` that expects a pointer... It's `scanf`, and the reason is clear. Have you ever tried writing a function that modifies it's arguments in such a way that's visible to the caller?

```
void test(int fubar) {
    fubar = 42; // this doesn't work
}
```

To be clear, `scanf` *needs to be able to assign* to an object that is *visible to the caller*, and C is strictly **pass-by-value** (meaning arguments are copies into temporary locations), so `scanf` needs a **reference type** (such as a pointer, passed by value, because C is strictly pass-by-value) in order to modify that which is referenced.

**You're missing an ampersand**, and your `scanf` wreaks of hideous guesswork. Change this: `scanf("%u \n", input);`

To this:

```
scanf("%u", &input);
         // ^--- see?
```

... and pick up a copy of K&R2e so you can read it and do the exercises post-haste...